# Search a text column for a string from a list, and return the found string

Tags: full-text-search, snowflake

I'm trying to search larger text for one of multiple values, lets say "Jack", "Jill", or "Bob" (the words can be 50 characters long).

With Snowflake I have something like

```
select count(*)
from my_table
where text_field like any ('%jack%', '%Jill%', %bob%')
```

That's roughly it. Now how do I indicate if the field contains `'jack'`, `'Jill'`, or `'bob'` specifically? I need to EXTRACT the found text. Also now imagine that instead of 3 values, there are a 100 values to search, so preferably not a solution where manual typing is involved like `charindex('jack')` or something like it.

I can store the values to search (100 words) in an another table. Let's call it `my_dictionary` with one column `my_word`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I'll post one possible solution for future reference -- not sure it's the most elegant --

But essentially with the dictionary of terms in another table

```
select
regexp_substr(big_text_field,
(select listagg(my_word,'|') from my_dictionary),
1,1,'i'), count(*)
from big_fact_table
group by
regexp_substr(big_text_field,
(select listagg(my_word,'|') from my_dictionary),
1,1,'i') -- little I that wants to capitalize in this bogus editor means case insensitive in snowflake
```